# UILabel: What is the difference between Plain and Attributed Text?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uilabel

I'm a newbie to iOS programming and I've tried looking around for answers but somehow can't find the answer to what I assume should be a basic question.

[image]

I noticed both is able to do the same thing, I am able to change the label name, set a custom font or system font and change the font weight, font size and stuff. So the question is, if *Plain* is able to do those, why and when do I use *Attributed*?

Thanks.

Comment: Simply you can do those with `plain`. but you cannot use different font ,size at same time with `pain`. Only you can do it with `Attributed`. You can get an idea from Apple Documentation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel

Comment: You mean combining 2 different font types and the like in a single UI Label?

Comment: yes. you can do it.

Comment: Okay, so if it's just going to be 1 single font type and the whole text holds the same font weight. Just using `plain` is enough? 

Since `Attributed` can do more, why just not use `Attributed` all the time? Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, "why do you use a super computer for simple calculation?"

Comment: Haha, that's one way to look at it. Thanks! I guess I'm just looking for reasons why it'll be wrong to use `Attributed` for something `plain` I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can understand difference between plain and attributed from their name.

**Plain** is `String` and as per [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string)

> **String**
>
> A Unicode string value is a series of characters, such as "Swift",
>   that forms a collection. Strings in Swift are Unicode correct and
>   locale insensitive, and are designed to be efficient

And as for **Attributed** `String` allow you to format ranges of text with custom colors, fonts, underlines, shadows, and more [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring)

> **NSAttributedString**
>
> A string that has associated attributes (such as visual style,
>   hyperlinks, or accessibility data) for portions of its text.An
>   NSAttributedString object manages character strings and associated
>   sets of attributes (for example, font and kerning) that apply to
>   individual characters or ranges of characters in the string. An
>   association of characters and their attributes is called an attributed
>   string. The cluster’s two public classes, NSAttributedString and
>   NSMutableAttributedString, declare the programmatic interface for
>   read-only attributed strings and modifiable attributed strings,
>   respectively.

Unless you have a specific reason to use `AttributedString`, you can pretty much forget that it exists.

[image]

Here is a good [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@suragch/attributed-strings-in-swift-7bb0ec582f94) on attributed String